# Extract values to points works for only part of a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, extract

I am trying to extract values from multiple rasters using the "Extract Multi Values to Points" tool in ArcGIS 10.8.  The tool works until it gets to a certain row and then returns no data for the remaining rows.

Using the identify tool I have verified values for multiple point locations in the raster, double checked that all rasters and the shapefile are in the same projections, and the shapefile is not a multifeature point feature. I've tried the tool multiple times and fave even tried to extract the data from a single raster with the same results.

Comment: Set environment extent to union of inputs.

Comment: Could you please inspect the results from the Sample tool?: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/sample.htm

Comment: How big are the rasters you are working with? Could there be a memory/space issue going on?